# How to separate auto-generated CSS code from HTML file in GWD?

Tags: html, css, google-web-designer

In Google Web Designer when we draw objects, the corresponding CSS classes are generated inside the same HTML file. Is there a way that we can specify to generate those in a different CSS file?

For example, when I draw circle in the index.html file I want to generate css classes in main.css file. That way, I can keep my code clean. Otherwise it is a lot of junk in same file.

Comment: I had the same thought..

Comment: I seperated the css after i have done my animations. I din't find a way to seperate it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible in GWD. Styles will always be generated directly in the HTML document; there's no option to use an external stylesheet instead.

<sup>Disclosure: I am an engineer on the Google Web Designer team.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to separate those files after publish the creative (code trans-pilling)

- Here is the documentation [Publish locally](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/3250387?hl=en)

[image]